# Automatically change comma delimiters to semicolons in VS/Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I'm converting some code from the C++ to C#, but there are comma-delimited instructions from C++ such as

```
a=5,b=3,c=4;
```

Is there a quick way to automatically convert it, in Visual Studio or Resharper, to code like this?:

```
a=5;
b=3;
c=4;
```

Comment: `Shift+Ctrl+F`, **[Find All]**, **Replace**.. Isn't that simple?

Comment: there's one quick replace feature, replace `,` with `;`. `Ctrl + H` is another shortcut

Comment: If it would be that simple, I would do it already. But except assignments, there are function calls, so the code could look like this:
    `myFunc(a,b,c,d);
    a=5,b=3,c=4;`
So replacing the comma would also affect the arguments in the function.

Comment: Why not leave it as is?

Comment: Because C# doesn't support comma-delimited instructions (at least it doesn't work with assignments)

Comment: Are you sure? Try something like  `int a = 5, b = 6; Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b);`

Comment: Those are not assignment statements, but variable declarations with initializers.

Comment: Of course, in case of **assignments** it should be rewritten somehow. It seems that originally comment was without clarification about assignments..